# How to copy file create/modify file to new file

Tags: python, file

File create/modify time has important information. When converting a file into new file, such as video, how to preserve create/modify time in Python. Something like:

```
# pseudo code
old_time = original_video.gettime()

# new_video and original_video are totally different files.
new_video = create_and_convert(original_video)

# How to copy old file create/modify time to new file?
set_time(new_video, old_time)
```

I wish new_video has exact same create/modify time. How to do it?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copystat

Answer (score 0):

Use [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module for your usecase.

```
import time
old_time = time.ctime()
```